# Sum of N reciprocals[Division mistake]

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std; 
int main()
{
  int n=0,tot=0;
  float sum = 0;
  float average = 0;
  float product = 1;


  cout<<"Type an integer and press Enter:\n";
  cin>>n;
  /*
     Your logic goes here
  */
  for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
       cout<<sum<<endl;
       sum= sum+(1/i);
       product=product*1/i;
       tot++;
   }
  cout<<"Sum, product and average of reciprocals are:\n"; 
  cout<<sum<<endl;
  cout<<product<<endl;
  cout<<average<<sum/tot<<endl;
}
```

Anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong , my sum is always equal to one, i don't know why. I put cout and at each iteration it printout "1". My logic is right but there is some mistake which i can't find.

Comment: `1/i` will be 0 for all `i` greater than 1. Integer division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line

```
sum= sum+(1/i);
```

Does integer division, when `i = 1` it will evaluate to 1, otherwise when i > 1, it will be 0.  I would use `1.0/i` to force floating point division

**EDIT:** I would make the change to your `product` update as well

Answer (score 1):

`1/i` will be 0 for all `i` greater than 1. Integer division. You will want to fix this by replacing `1/i` with `1.0/i`.

See ideone [here](https://ideone.com/5OYEAf)